# Sending Command to comport using batch file in loop

Tags: batch-file

Below is my code-

```
mode COM20 BAUD=115200 PARITY=n DATA=8

SET CMD="&511401120013FF0B7207010801020304050607250152"
FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,1) DO (
echo %CMD% > COM20
)
pause
```

I am not getting this command on COM 20, I am monitoring it  on one of the serial port monitor.

What can be the cause?

Answer (score 2):

`echo %CMD% > COM20:` or `echo %CMD% > \\.\COM20` should send *some string* to the `COM20:` port. Note that `COM20` is a regular file name in the *Win32 **File** Namespace* category, see [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Do not use the following reserved names for the name of a file:
>   
> CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7,
>   COM8, COM9, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, and LPT9.
>   Also avoid these names followed immediately by an extension; for
>   example, NUL.txt is not recommended. For more information, see
>   [Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#namespaces). 
> …
>   *Win32 **Device** Namespaces* 
> The "`\\.\`" prefix will access the Win32 device namespace instead of the Win32 file namespace. This is
>   how access to physical disks and volumes is accomplished directly,
>   without going through the file system, if the API supports this type
>   of access. You can access many devices other than disks this way
>   (using the CreateFile and DefineDosDevice functions, for example).
>   
> For example, if you want to open the system's serial
>   communications port 1, you can use "`COM1`" in the call to the
>   CreateFile function. This works because `COM1`–`COM9` are part of the
>   reserved names in the NT namespace, although using the "`\\.\`" prefix
>   will also work with these device names. By comparison, if you have a
>   100 port serial expansion board installed and want to open `COM56`, you
>   cannot open it using "`COM56`" because there is no predefined NT
>   namespace for `COM56`. You will need to open it using "`\\.\COM56`"
>   because "`\\.\`" goes directly to the device namespace without
>   attempting to locate a predefined alias.

However, note that `echo %CMD% > \\.\COM20` would send double quotes *and* the space preceding the `>` redirection operator *and* final `<CR><LF>`, i.e. <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
rem                                      this space ↓
echo "&511401120013FF0B7207010801020304050607250152"  1>\\.\COM20
rem  ↑              these double quotes            ↑
```

You could use

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
mode COM20: BAUD=115200 PARITY=n DATA=8

SET "CMD=&511401120013FF0B7207010801020304050607250152"
rem ↑      note the opening double quote position

FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,1) DO (

    rem next command suppresses double quotes and final `<CR><LF>` output
    <NUL set /P "=!CMD!">\\.\COM20

    rem OR next command suppresses double quotes output
    rem echo !CMD!>\\.\COM20
)
```